# What does it mean when my influence level is "dominant"?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

So my influence level has passed "influential" and is now "dominant". I know "influential" over enough civilizations is enough to secure the cultural victory, but what does "dominant" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this source](http://well-of-souls.com/civ/civ5_bravenewworld.html#tourism), the tourism/culture levels are broken down like this:

- "Exotic" (10%)
- "Familiar" (30%)
- "Popular" (60%)
- "Influential" (100%+)
- "Dominant" (200%)

Being "dominant" over another civilization affects [public opinion and preferred ideology](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Ideology_(Civ5)#Public_Opinion_and_Preferred_Ideology).  This means it is possible for other civilizations to conform to your ideology (if they are following another ideology) and impacts whether or not your ideology is "preferred".  Following a "preferred" ideology can greatly impact your civilization's happiness, so it should not be taken lightly!  Hope this helps!

***EDIT:***

Basically, influence levels dictate how much ideology pressure is applied to other civilization. Having a "dominant" influence would exert more ideological pressure to the other civilization. Besides that, there is really no difference between "influential" and "dominant" levels.

Answer (score 1):

Dominant is the level of cultural influence above Influential, achieved at 200%. It doesn't contribute towards cultural victory but it does contribute to your influence over their ideology.

Being Influential over a civilization with a different ideology than you contributes towards the amount of unhappiness they receive from it. This can, in extreme cases, force them to change ideology or cause their cities to defect to you.

Answer (score 0):

Dominant is basically the same as influential, you just exert at least twice as much influence over a civs ideology as you would if you were merely influential.